# Scalar Matrix and Diag Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

1. A set of all **diagonal** matrices (nxn) over R is a field relatively to additive and multiply operations on matrices.
2. A set of all **scalar** matrices (nxn) over C is a field relatively to additive and multiply operations on matrices.

I can assure you that (1.) is wrong and (2.) is right, but I want to make sure that I proved it right, I'd like your help to confirm that.

My solution:
For (1.) I said that if a diagonal matrix has a zero in its diagonal so $a*a^-1 =1$ won't be true, and it's pretty simple to see: $0*0 \ne 1$

and for (2.) I said that you can't choose the zero value as a scalar because it will be the zero matrix and $ a * a^-1 = 1 $ won't work, is that right to say that zero can't be a scalar? I'm wondering because I know that the zero matrix IS a scalar matrix and I also know from the answers that (2.) must be true which means $ a * a^-1 = 1 $ has to work. Will be glad for some explanation help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1.) Note that a field is allowed to have one non-product-invertible element, the additive identity. The problem with this set is that there are non-invertible **non-zero** elements, such as $\left(\matrix{1 \; 0 \\ 0\; 0}\right)$ in $M_{2x2}(\mathbb{R})$

(2.) Again, a field can have a $0$ element , and that's $0$. After all that set is $\mathbb{C}$ via a very simple bijective map

Comment: If a scalar will be zero then $ (0 + i *0) *(  0 + i * 0) \ne 1$ which makes (2.) not a field over C, can u explain again please?

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you're trying to say.
May I suggest you look up the definition of a field, especially the part about invertible elements? I believe everything will become clear then

Comment: Multiplicative inverse: There exists an element b for all nonzero a such that ab=1 from [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Fields)

Comment: Yeah, the "nonzero" part is the key.
On $\mathbb{C}$ (hence on the scalar matrices set) $0+i*0 = 0$ by definition, if that's the problem. If anything, writing "$0$" instead of "$0+i0$" is a bit incorrect, but understandable.